# How can I clear the console in Java without clearing user input

Tags: java

How would I be able to clear the console in Java without it clearing any text that has been inputed by the user?

I have an application that clears the screens and re writes it every second. But it doesn't keep what I type in. I need to be able to preserve the user input until enter is pressed. Is there a way to do this?
Thanks :)

Comment: You will likely need to turn off the standard terminal echo functionality to take in each character as it is inputted but the user and redraw it when the screen is cleared. Can you show the code you use for clearing the screen?

Comment: @joshmeranda
Yeah, I just use a process builder to call a command depending if its on windows or Mac.
`processBuilder.command("clear");`